# Jesus withdrawing from his disciples to pray

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, gospel-of-luke, textual-discrepancies, gospel-of-mark

In Matthew 26:36-46 and Mark 14:32-42, Jesus moves away three times from his apostles to pray in the Garden of Gethsemane.

What is the biblical basis as to why Luke has Jesus pray only once in Luke 22:39-46?

Comment: Welcome. As phrased, this question is pretty opinion-based and thus isn't well-suited for this site.  Your definition of a "good explanation" may be different from that of others.  On the other hand, we *could* answer a question like, "how are the events of Matthew 26, Mark 14, and Luke 22 reconciled by people who believe the Bible is inerrant?"   If that's suitable, please edit the question, or confirm here so that someone can edit it for you.  I hope you'll also take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Answer (score 3):

**Luke doesn't say Jesus prayed "only once"**, it records him praying without noting the particular detail of the three separate entreaties recorded in Matthew and Mark (although perhaps it is alluded to non-specifically in verse 44 - "he prayed more earnestly" in context suggests **he prayed at least twice**):

> <sup>39</sup> Jesus went out as usual to the Mount of Olives, and his disciples followed him. <sup>40</sup> On reaching the place, he said to them, “Pray that you will not fall into temptation.” <sup>41</sup> He withdrew about a stone’s throw beyond them, knelt down and prayed, <sup>42</sup> “Father, if you are willing, take this cup from me; yet not my will, but yours be done.” <sup>43</sup> An angel from heaven appeared to him and strengthened him. <sup>44</sup> And being in anguish, he prayed more earnestly, and his sweat was like drops of blood falling to the ground.
>
> <sup>45</sup> When he rose from prayer and went back to the disciples, he found them asleep, exhausted from sorrow. <sup>46</sup> “Why are you sleeping?” he asked them. “Get up and pray so that you will not fall into temptation.” - [Luke 22:39-46 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2022%3A39-46&version=NIV)

**There is a big difference between lack of detail and a denial of detail.**